# List which have different objects

Tags: java

Lets say i have

```
class Person {
    String Age;
    String Name;
}

Class Employee  {
    int Salary;
    String Name;
}
```

I have various instances of these classes which are in a list.
I have created 2 separate function which accepts `List<Person>` and `List<Employee>` and display the contents.
but i want to create a generic function which accepts List of any object and do the display part.

Please help me

Thanks
Sunny

Comment: What about having Employee extends Person and using a single list of Person ?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution is to let `Employee` inherit from `Person`. This is natural, since most likely an Employee **is** a Person. They even share some attributes, like `Name` (which you already had in your code) and `Age`.

```
class Person {
    String Age;
    String Name;
}

class Employee  extends Person {
    int Salary;
    // String Name; not needed anymore, inherited from Person
}
```

Then, it is sufficient to have a list of Persons `List<Person>`, where you can store both object types.

If you still need to keep them separate for any reason, you could add a common parent class or interface. Ideally add the necessary methods (like displaying) into the interface and let the classes implement them:

```
interface Human {
   void showMe();
}

class Person implements Human {
    String Age;
    String Name;

    public void showMe() { System.out.println("I am a Person!");  }
}

class Employee implements Human {
    int Salary;
    String Name;

    public void showMe() { System.out.println("I am an Employee!");  }
}
```

You can then use a list of `Human`s to store both object types. Iterating becomes quite easy then:

```
List<Human> humanList = new ArrayList<>();
// ... Populate the list with Persons and Employees

for(Human human : humanList) {
    human.showMe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should'have made Employee extend Person so you could have one generic function for display.

Another way could be to have a common interface to Person and Employee with the same display function but two different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but something like this:

```
public interface MyInterface{
public void display();
}

class Person implments MyInterface{

String Age;
String Name;

@Override
public void display(){
   //Logic to print the data
}
}

Class Employee  implments MyInterface{
int Salary;
String Name;
@Override
public void display(){
   //Logic to print the data
}
}

public class MyTest{

public static void main(String[] args){

  List<MyInterface> myList = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();

    MyInterface p = new Person();
    MyInterface e = new Person();
    myList.add(p);
myList.add(e);
printMyList(myList);

}

private void printMyList(  List<MyInterface> myList){
   for(MyInterface my:myList){
     my.display();
}
}
}
```